# protected inheritance - why a certain command is not allowed

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class A
    {
    public:
        void foo() const {}
    };

    class B : protected A
    {
    public:
    void print() const
    {
        foo();
    }
    };

    void main()
    {

    B b;
    b.print();
    b.foo();
    }
```

Now, by reading [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance), I conclude that in case of protected inheritance, every public member of the base (for that matter - class A)  will be acsessible in the derived class (class B).

However, I dont understand why the command     `b.foo();` is not allowed in this case, becuase it  apparently  seems to be allowed according to the rules of protected inheritance.

Comment: It might help to pretend `B` declares a `protected: void foo() const;`. The same access restrictions apply.

Comment: The access rules state that `B` can access `foo` but in `b.foo();` it's not `B` doing the accessing but you

Comment: **in** is the keyword. The scope of main is not in there, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access B::foo() from the scope of main(). As foo is not public in this context, it's not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, only the `class B` "knows" or "is aware" of the inherent relationship between `class A` and itself due to the relationship being `protected`. Namely, `main()` doesn't know of said relationship.